# To find the two dimensional subspace of $R^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am stuck with this question .Kindly help me to get through this

[image]

Option A is of 1 dimension so it cannot be answer but all other options are looking fine to me , What i am missing ? THANKS

Comment: (d) looks ambiguous: the variable $x$ is not quantified, and the variable $y$ does not appear in $(0,x,z)$.

Comment: @Siminore it looks like a typo, should say $(0,y,z)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether option (b) is really closed under addition. What happens when you add say $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. Does the sum belong to the union described in (b)?

Also try to imagine what this union is a union of and so what is looks like ... But in fact you should check the subspace requirements for all of them to gain confidence in the subject!

Comment: B Means points on x and y axis

Comment: @godonichia: Be careful. Although the letters are $x$ and $y$, they are not placed as first and second coordinates. Apart from that you are correct - it is the union of two of the axes.

Comment: Why sum doesnot belong to b

Comment: Option b is not clear to me

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

The union of two subspaces isn't a subspace unless one contains the other. (Try to work out the simple reason why this is so.)

A subspace must contain $(0,0,0)$

Comment: c doesnot contain (0,0).

Comment: @godonichia That's correct...

Comment: B means union of y and z axis respectively .they have 0,0 in common only so not a subspace . Am i right ?

Comment: @godonichia If $V$ is any subspace, $V$ and $\{(0,0)\}$ only share the origin, and yet their union is a subspace. So you're not really adequately explaining why the union of subspaces that don't contain each other is not a subspace.

Comment: @rschweib what should be proper reasoning for b

Comment: @godonichia As previously suggested, the right thing to look at is additive closure.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is looking at the basis of the subspace given. For example, the basis of question (c) given is $\{(1,0,0)(0,1,0)\}$. So the dimension of this subspace which consists of two elements in the basis is two.